# How to get permission with NSSavePanel in sandbox environment

Tags: objective-c

There is a project with sandbox environment, right now i want to let users choose a dir to save files. For example, when user choose "Desktop" in the save panel, then i will save file to the dir "~/Desktop".
The code is as below:

```
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    NSInteger result = [savePanel runModal];
    if(result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        NSString *dir = [savePanel.URL.path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.txt"];
        NSError *err;
        NSLog(@"%@",dir);
        [@"asasasa" writeToFile:dir atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
        NSLog(@"%@",err);
    }
```

The error happens that `Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “2.txt” in the folder “Desktop”.`

I have already enable `Read/Write` of `User Selected File` in the `Capabilities` settings. Anybody can tell me what should i do right now ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `NSOpenPanel` to choose a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the file to the URL you got permission for, you changed the URL. **This is not allowed**.

Specify `2.txt` in the save panel so the URL you get back is `~/Desktop/2.txt`. Then saving will work.

---

Side note: There is also an URL related API like `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error` and `URLByAppendingPathComponent:`